# ibus not working in Kubuntu 18.04 KDE Plasma

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, ibus

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 (installed by kubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso), and I want to input Chinese. So I installed IBus, but it is not working. I used the following steps to install IBus:

1. sudo apt-install ibus ibus-qt4 ibus-gkt ibus-libpinyin ibs-m17n
2. run ibus-daemon -drx
3. run ibus-setup, and choose Chinese pinyin input method
4. open a Kate, choose input method, and it not working

Then, I configured IBUS following this wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Chinese

firstly,

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

secondly,

```
install qt4-qtconfig
```

then run

```
qtconfig-qt4
```

and Interface > Default Input Method, select ibus instead of xim.

thirdly,

```
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus to ~/.xprofile (make a file)
```

then, reboot OS，but it is still not working, what's wrong with my operation?

Comment: Try `fcitx` instead? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx#fcitx_and_KDE

Comment: Thanks, I am try run  “ sudo im-config", not "im-config", then choose ibus input method, then it works. im-config cmd need root author to display input method chooser.

Comment: Note: I think there is a typo in your first step, you probably mean: `sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-qt4 ibus-gtk ibus-libpinyin ibus-m17n`. That is, `apt-get install` instead of `apt-install`, and `ibus-gtk` instead of `ibus-gkt`, and `ibus-m17n` instead of `ibs-m17n`. I assume that this typo is only in this post, but that you typed the correct thing in your terminal, since `apt-install` would directly return an obvious error.